# How to convert an RDD of Maps to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have RDD of Map and i want to converted it to dataframe 
Here is the input format of RDD

```
val mapRDD: RDD[Map[String, String]] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   Map("empid" -> "12", "empName" -> "Rohan", "depId" -> "201"),
   Map("empid" -> "13", "empName" -> "Ross", "depId" -> "201"),
   Map("empid" -> "14", "empName" -> "Richard", "depId" -> "401"),
   Map("empid" -> "15", "empName" -> "Michale", "depId" -> "501"),
   Map("empid" -> "16", "empName" -> "John", "depId" -> "701")))
```

is there any way to convert into dataframe like

```
 val df=mapRDD.toDf
```

df.show

```
empid,  empName,    depId
12      Rohan       201
13      Ross        201
14      Richard     401
15      Michale     501
16      John        701
```

Comment: "I have Map of RDD" - to be more accurate, you have "an RDD of Maps".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily convert it into Spark DataFrame:

Here is a code that would do the trick :

```
val mapRDD= sc.parallelize(Seq(
   Map("empid" -> "12", "empName" -> "Rohan", "depId" -> "201"),
   Map("empid" -> "13", "empName" -> "Ross", "depId" -> "201"),
   Map("empid" -> "14", "empName" -> "Richard", "depId" -> "401"),
   Map("empid" -> "15", "empName" -> "Michale", "depId" -> "501"),
   Map("empid" -> "16", "empName" -> "John", "depId" -> "701")))

val columns=mapRDD.take(1).flatMap(a=>a.keys)

val resultantDF=mapRDD.map{value=>
      val list=value.values.toList
      (list(0),list(1),list(2))
      }.toDF(columns:_*)

resultantDF.show()
```

The output is :

```
+-----+-------+-----+
|empid|empName|depId|
+-----+-------+-----+
|   12|  Rohan|  201|
|   13|   Ross|  201|
|   14|Richard|  401|
|   15|Michale|  501|
|   16|   John|  701|
+-----+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Just note that this assumes that the first record you pull has all of the keys.  E.g., if the first record was missing `depId` for instance, then the output DF would not have `depId`, even if all the other records had that.